# Getting imported files from sample java program to new program

Tags: eclipse, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to make a small java program revolving around Google Calendars. I've never worked with java before but I was able to get Google's sample code working. In Eclipse, I simply used Import -> Maven, and then made some small changes to the code so that it worked on my Calendar.

Ok, great, now I want to write my own code. I started a new project and imported the Google Calendar API. At the very beginning, there are several import actions:

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
.
.
.
```

It turns out that I'm missing the second and third files. How do I find these files and how to do import them to the new project?

Please note: I ultimately don't want to rely on importing the Google Calendar API or anything similar, as I will be using another non-java program to run and control this one.

---

Here's what I tried:

I go back to the sample code, expand Maven Dependencies and find:

```
google-oauth-client-jetty-1.19.0.jar
google-oauth-client-java6-1.19.0.jar
```

I see that these files are in:

```
C:\******\.m2\repository\com\google\oauth-client\google-oauth-client-jetty\1.19.0
C:\******\.m2\repository\com\google\oauth-client\google-oauth-client-java6\1.19.0
```

I tried to add these with Import -> Java EE -> App Client JAR file
Didn't work, do I need to change the file name or import name? Maybe these aren't the correct files anyway.

I also tried to add these by creating a lib folder in my project folder and add the JAR files directly there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess from your question your project is just an Eclipse project rather than a Maven project. Obviously Maven automatically add the required jars of the dependencies stated in pom.xml for example google-oauth-client-java6-1.19.0.jar is a dependency of google-oauth-client-jetty-1.19.0.jar.

To add external jar to your project in Eclipse you need to select the project then from the Project menu select Properties. On the properties popup click on the Java Build Path, you have two options depending where the jars are stored, if you are referring to the maven .m2 directory then choose 'Add External Jars' otherwise if you added them to a lib folder in the project choose Add Jars

[image]

Comment: I ended up solving this myself, and the last bit is what I needed to do. I transferred the files to a new "lib" folder. Then in eclipse, I right-clicked on the project and selected refresh. The lib folder then appears in my project, and all the jar files within the folder. Finally, one by one in eclipse, I right clicked and added them to my build path.